# Can't figure out how to show second dropdown

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I've been looking a lot at this problem, but I can't find the bug hiding. Somehow it's overlapping, and I can't get the second menu to show up.

```
#menu > ul > li.has-dropdown = first
#menu > ul > li.has-dropdown > ul > li.has-dropdown = second
```

`now #menu > ul > li.has-dropdown > ul > li.has-dropdown > ul` shows up, but with no text, all transparent, I can't get it to show somehow.

Website link : 
http://rscomposites.101-odense.dk/

Comment: Please post here your code.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please reword the title to be a more specific/technical question - that way anyone else with the same problem will find it when they search (there are zillions of dropdown set-ups, and zillions of things that might go wrong)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove "overflow:hidden" from ul.dropdown and it will show. Just use the developer panel in your browser (F12) and you will find things like this.
By the way, there are several existing drop down menus on the internet you can use and just apply your style to it without having to deal with problems like this.

Comment: Thank you :-) .. Stressed day.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use this method:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href=''>First</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href=''>Dropdown</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
<ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul{list-style-type:none;padding:0px;margin:0px;}
ul>li>ul{display:none;position:absolute;}
ul>li:hover>ul{display:block;}
```